# AngularJS scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a weird case of angular scope mixup. Here's the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/o8cyZXkHX8Lt9Vkbn0xm

The transcluded scope does not resolve `appCtrl.testString`, which is strange, because transcluded content should have the outside scope. What's even more strange is that `num` gets resolved correctly.

Also, `data-test-attr` gets the correct value on the element that `ng-controller` is defined.

This is a minimal working example, so solutions with reordering the elements or defining a scope in a different place do not really suit me. I'd rather hack the `repeatedDirective` somehow, if that's at all possible.

Here's the code:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <repeated-directive ng-repeat="num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" ng-controller="AppController as appCtrl" data-test-attr="{{appCtrl.testString}}">
      <div>{{num}} - {{appCtrl.testString}}</div>
    </repeated-directive>
  </body>

</html>
```

`script.js`

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AppController', AppController)
  .directive('repeatedDirective', repeatedDirective);

function AppController($scope) {
  this.testString = 'Controller value';
}

function repeatedDirective() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is not in scope of your directive:

this fixes it without changing anything in your html:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AppController', AppController)
  .directive('repeatedDirective', repeatedDirective);

function AppController($scope) {
  this.testString = 'Controller value';
}

function repeatedDirective() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      transclude(scope, function(clone, scope) {
        element.append(clone);
      });
    }
  };
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LsRfyw98f4BP4G72Bgd6?p=preview

This way your transclusion does not use a seperate scope but takes the scope of the controller.

e voila

for more information on what exactly is happening I will include a reference blog :

http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/

Answer (score 0):

Within your `ng-repeat`, you have your scope of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and not the `appCtrl` which explains the empty value of `testString` (actually it is unexisting). You should access the `$parent` to be able to have your `appCtrl` scope.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <repeated-directive ng-repeat="num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" ng-controller="AppController as appCtrl" data-test-attr="{{appCtrl.testString}}">
      <div>{{num}} - {{$parent.appCtrl.testString}}</div>
    </repeated-directive>
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qc3j0nsJZKypXSsqMEqx